# C++ structure reference from member reference

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

Given the following setup...

```cpp
struct A {unsigned char _data;};
struct B {unsigned char _data;};
struct C {A a; B b;};

// in this context (ar) is known to be the "a" of some C instance
A& ar = ...;
B& br = get_sister(ar); // the "b" of the same C instance that (ar) belongs to
C& cr = get_parent(ar); // the C instance that (ar) belongs to
```

...how do I get `br` and `cr` from `ar` without UB (undefined behaviour)?

Comment: You can't an `A&` has no idea about where else the object is being referenced from

Comment: Well, you would have to track that information yourself. Nothing in the language can let you find the enclosing structure.

Comment: For standard layout types like you show, `a` and its "parent" are pointer interconvertible, so not much trouble there. In the more general case, this is unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you know **for a fact** that `ar` is referencing a `C::a` member, then you can use [`offsetof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) (which *should* return 0 in this case, since `a` is the 1st non-static data member of `C`, but best not to assume that) to help you access the `C` object, eg:

```
C& get_parent(A& ar)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<C*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ar) - offsetof(C, a));
}

B& get_sister(A& ar)
{
    return get_parent(ar).b;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/XmWugY)

Comment: I believe `uintptr_t` would make more semantic sense instead of `char*`

Comment: Note that the class may need to be standard layout (such as it is in the example).

Comment: @Vye doesn't really matter either way. Any object pointer is allowed to be casted to a `char*` pointer for purposes of accessing the object's raw bytes, and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to always be 1 byte. So whether casting to `char*` or `uintptr_t`, the end effect is the same.

Comment: @eerorika can you think of an example where `offsetof()` of a data member would not work for a non-standard-layout class?

Comment: @RemyLebeau A language implementation that doesn't implement `offsetof` for non-standard-layout classes.